# Проверка возврата непустого значения

Tags: python, dict

Кидаю GET-запрос. Получаю ответ в виде ключ-значение. Это тест и надо, чтоб он падал, если одно из значений пустое. Подскажите, как?

```
 r = requests.get(url + 'api/v1/currency/RUB/USD/CASH/')
reqs = r.content.decode('utf-8')
print(r.status_code)
print(reqs)

dict = json.loads(reqs)
print(dict)

print(dict["data"]["rate_kind"])
print(dict["data"]["curr_buy"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через `if` и `get` проверяйте элементы у словаря. Т.к. если запрашивать через квадратные скобки `rs['data']`, то при отсутствии элемента будет выброшено исключение [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError), а при запросе через `get` `rs.get('data')` при отсутствии ключа вернется `None`:

```
rs = json.loads(reqs)
print('Ответ:', rs)

if not rs:
    raise Exception('Пустой ответ!')

if not rs.get("data"):
    raise Exception('В ответе отсутствует или пустое поле "data"')

if not rs.get("data").get("rate_kind"):
    raise Exception('В ответе отсутствует или пустое поле "data/rate_kind"')

if not rs.get("data").get("curr_buy"):
    raise Exception('В ответе отсутствует или пустое поле "data/curr_buy"')

print(rs["data"]["rate_kind"])
print(rs["data"]["curr_buy"])
```

Оператор `if not ...` тут сможет проверить элемент на пустоту (пустая строка `""`, пустой список `[]`, пустой словарь `{}`, отсутствует `None`, и т.п.)

---

**PS.** не используйте в качестве имени переменной `dict`, т.к. это название встроенной функции ([вот список](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)) и после объявления этой переменной не сможете использовать эту функцию

Comment: Спасибо большое, Сейчас попробую и отпишусь

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо!

Comment: @СергейБогданов, пожалуйста :)

Comment: @ gil9red Этот код проверяет наличие ключей а вот как проверить что значение у этих ключей не пустое?

Comment: @СергейБогданов, почему вы решили что значения не проверяются? Код проверяет и значения ключей.  Об этом я писал в самом ответе `Оператор if not ... тут сможет проверить элемент ...`

Comment: Я сэмулировал ответ сервиса. удалил значение ключа и ошибки не было. Ошибка валилась только если я сам ключ менял

Comment: @СергейБогданов, для тестирования кода не обязательно эмуляции сервера, достаточно создать питоничий словарь -- вы можете в консоль его вывести, скопировать и вставить в код, и с ним играться. Так я создал `rs = {
    'data': {
        'rate_kind': ''
    }
}
` и при запуске проверки выдало `Exception: В ответе отсутствует или пустое поле "data/rate_kind"`

Comment: я ошибочно написал. Я так и сделал. Взял ответ и игрался с ним)

Comment: Тогда покажите пример неправильного `rs`, который пропускают те проверки :)

Comment: все. Разобрался. Прошу прощения. Почему то так вел себя с моей локалки. А как только запушил и дернули TeamCity иг Git, все ок. Спасибо большое за помощь)

Comment: @СергейБогданов, пожалуйста :)